# commnication between Arduino UNO and MEGA

Tags: arduino, gps, xbee

I am trying to send the `GPS` values from  `Arduino UNO` to `Arduino MEGA` through `XBee S1` using TX0 & RX0 ports.

I have transferred `GPS` values From `Arduino UNO` - `Arduino UNO`, and now I am able to transfer data from `Arduino UNO` but unable to read the data at Arduino MEGA.

Connections at `Arduino MEGA`

'XBee' shield - 'Arduino MEGA'
  3.3 VCC   -----      3.3 VCC
  GND-----GND
2--------RX0
3--------TX0
Can any one help me.

Comment: Have you tried swapping RX and TX? If so, then first check with an oscilloscope if there is some signal on the wire (the pin connected to RX0), otherwise I suppose your Xbee shield has 3.3V outputs. If so, try connecting two resistors to boost the voltage. For instance use a 10k from 2 to RX0 and a 47k from RX0 to 5V. If you have a small silicon diode (1N4148) you can make a better circuit: 1N4148 from 2 to RX0 (cathode to 2, anode to RX0) and a 10k resistor from 5V to RX0 (and the anode of the diode). Make these tries and let us know

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, I have tried by swapping RX and TX but also am not getting values. The processors are different in `Arduino MEGA` and `Arduino UNO` I think that might be an issue. I am trying to solve that, if I get the solution, I will let you know.